# Why does an element still take up space even when height is 0?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Here's the demo: https://codepen.io/jchi2241/pen/dEzMZo?editors=1100

I am hiding the `<ul>` with a max-height of 0 when the sibling input element is unchecked, and setting the `<ul>` max-height to 10em when checked. I am using max-height specifically to animate the opening and closing for each section.

However, what I've realized is the `<ul>` is taking up a noticeable amount of space below the `<label>` even when the max-height is 0. This is obvious if you delete the `<ul>` element or set the `<ul>` to `position: absolute` or `display: none` taking it out of the DOM flow. I don't want to use either methods as that will not allow for the transition animation.

So to get back to the original question - what is causing the `<ul>` to take up space below the `<label>` even when it's height is set to 0? What is the ideal way to rid of this space while maintaining the transition animation?

Comment: It prevents margin collapse. Look up that term.

Comment: for space below ul, you can use "margin-bottom:0"

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself. Don't make us go off site to find critical information. Preferably use StackSnippets to create a [MCVE]

Comment: ^ see codepen link in post

Comment: Codepen is not in the question itself, make it as easy as possible for us to help you. Please see : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Note in point 1: **in the question itself**. If codepen goes down, we lose critical information for the question at hand. Everything required to answer the question needs to be provided **in the question itself** , not an external link.

Answer (score 1):

Add an overflow:hidden to the element, as well as set the max-height:0

That should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This gap is because of `<a>` that is located inside of `<li>`. When `<li>` contains `<a>` and you click on input to fire the animation, you need to set `display:off` to remove this space and again set `display:on` to back the `<a>` to `<li>`.

[image]

The right side picture shows less space after setting `displaying:off` on tag `<a>`.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct CSS. So [far as I'm aware](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#syntax), the possible values for the `display` rule do not include `on` or `off`. Maybe you meant `none`?

Also, you finish your answer using a different CSS rule you call `displaying`. Again, so far as I'm aware, there is [no such rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/displaying) with that name.

I would edit the answer, but SO has too many pending edits currently.